# Search for a string in packet bytes of a pcap file using tshark

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I am able to search for a string in the in packet bytes of a pcap capture using Wireshark. Is there similar functionality available in tshark ?

I already have the pcap files. But I need to go through them quickly to find the matching strings in the packet bytes.

Comment: Neither Wireshark nor tshark are security tools. I'm not sure why you are asking here,

Comment: @schroeder both wireshark and tshark can be used for security control testing.

Comment: Sure, and so can a lot of things, but they are not *security* tools.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to find packets containing strings of interest using either the *contains* or *matches* operators, depending on your needs.  For example:

```
tshark -r foo.pcap -Y "frame contains foo"
```

For more information on Wireshark display filters, refer to the [wireshark-filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) man page.